# What is the 'end' parameter for PathMetric extractPath

Tags: flutter

I am looking at the [PathMetric.extractPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PathMetric/extractPath.html) method.

I am confused as to what exactly the 'end' parameter is supposed to be? I don't know what the path length is, I only know that I want to extract 80% percent of the path. How is this achieved?

Comment: some code would be useful. 80% of what do you need? a screen or a widget?

Comment: 80% of the distance from the start of the pathmetric to the end.

Comment: I've misunderstood the question, isn't that what you need? `metric.extractPath(0, metric.length * 0.8);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `end` parameter specifies where on the path you want the extraction to stop.

In the `PathMetric` class, you have access to the path `length`. So if you want 80% of the path, you could use:

`Path extractedPath = pathMetric.extractPath(0, pathMetric.length * 0.8);`

If your path is closed and you want to extract a portion from the end of the path that overlaps the beginning of the path. you could extract the path to the end and then for the overlapping, extract another path from the beginning. Then combine the two.

```
double extraRemainingFromEnd = end - pathMetric.length;

Path extractionToEnd = pathMetric.extractPath(start, pathMetric.length);
Path overlapFromBeginning = pathMetric.extractPath(0, extraRemainingFromEnd);

Path newPath = extractionToEnd..addPath(overlapFromBeginning , const Offset(0, 0));
```

Or even better you could make an extension on the `PathMetric`:

```
extension on PathMetric {
  Path extractPathfromClosed(double start, double end) {

    if (end <= length || !isClosed) return extractPath(start, end);

    Path overlapFromBeginning = extractPath(0, end - length);

    return extractPath(start, length)..addPath(overlapFromBeginning, const Offset(0, 0));
  }
}
```

now you can use `extractPathfromClosed` directly from your `PathMetric` instance.